# How to start session in web application after login in MEAN technology

Tags: angularjs, node.js, session, mean-stack, mean

I am new in MEAN technology and Developing Web APP. I established the

Connection and  login successfully. I want to establish the session after login

But I don't know how to established the session in MEAN app.

Connection established using  **app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// database connectivity
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ditroapp');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('mongo connection error', err);
});

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log('mongo connected.');
});

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

and here is code in controller.js using this I login successful.

```
$scope.loginpage = function(){
        $http({
          method: 'POST',
          url: '/api/login',
          data: {email:$scope.email, password:$scope.password}
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if(response.data.error)
            {
                alert("Invalid email pasword");
            }
            else 
            {

                $scope.dp = response.data;
                $localStorage.pp = $scope.dp;
                //console.log($localStorage.pp)
                $location.path('/addseat');

            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          alert("Invalid email pasword");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Session in API environment does not make sense. When you login server returns a token and client app (angular in your case) keeps that and use in every request to API in request header. So when a request entered to API goes through some middlewares that one of them is authentication middleware. You need to look at this mechanism as stateless. Maybe this link is useful https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens or http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543

Comment: Try express-session with passportjs 
https://github.com/expressjs/session and
http://passportjs.org/docs

Eg: http://code.runnable.com/VSlknUT7ZMZpp-2v/authentication-with-passport-for-node-js-session-express-and-login